# Using ion radiation to make electricity?

Tags: nuclear-physics, radiation, nuclear-engineering

Is it possible to capture the ion radiation from a nuclear source and make electricity from it? I always thought it was possible, but never looked into it? Is this what a beta voltaic battery does?

Comment: Yes, that is what beta- (for electrons) or, in the case of ions alpha-voltaic devices do. Applications have been rather limited, so far, as far as I know, but there seem to be a few commercial devices.

Comment: Related, and possibly interesting reading: [Why aren't betavoltaics and alphavoltaics batteries widely used?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/83821/why-arent-betavoltaics-and-alphavoltaics-batteries-widely-used)

Comment: A problem I see is that the current generated that way will be only a very small part of the total energy released by the radiation. For efficiency you need to capture **all** the energy

Comment: Is it possible to use a electromagnetism to capture all the possible ions coming from the radioactive material? or is this how betavoltiacs work?